# How to fix invalid prop 'color' suplied to 'icon'?

Tags: react-native

I’m setting up a new component with an icon from the "react-native-vector-icons" and I got a yellow warning.

This is for a new feature of the icon

```
Dashboard: {
        screen: DashboardStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'HOME',
            tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => handleTabPress(navigation, defaultHandler),
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                // HERE IS THE PROBLEM //
            return <SSIcon name={'home'} size={20} color={focused ? GStyle.GREEN : Color(GStyle.BLACK).alpha(.45)} />

            },

        }
    },
```

I expect for no yellow warning

Comment: What is Color from Color(GStyle.BLACK).alpha(.45) and GStyle.GREEN ?

Comment: " Color(GStyle.BLACK).alpha(.45)  " is grey color and " GStyle.GREEN" is green color

Comment: in your app index.js add this line : console.disableYellowBox = true;

Comment: @AnkushRishi is not solve the problem, is just ignore warnings alert

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code

```
 <SSIcon name={'home'} size={20} color={focused ? "green" : "black"} />
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried separating the color instead?

```
const stackNav = createStackNavigator ({
Dashboard: {
        screen: DashboardStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'HOME',
            tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => handleTabPress(navigation, defaultHandler),
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => <SSIcon name={'home'} size={20} color={tintColor} />


        }

}}, {
  tabBarOptions: { 
     activeTintColor:GStyle.GREEN,
     inactiveTintColor: Color(GStyle.BLACK).alpha(.45)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

> in your application's root `index.js` add this line:

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

Comment: is not solve the problem, is just ignore warnings alert